# IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 in pandas/matlplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

SO I am getting this error and I don't understand why because this should run okay... The error is in this part where I declare aeol.

```
        import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/nm-static/deepex_fall2020/DeepEx_W3_20201217_slt_data.csv"

df= pd.read_csv(url)
end = max(df['lt_id']) + 1
for i in range(1,end):
  test = df.loc[df['lt_id'] == i]
  load = test['load']
  disp = test['displacement']
  aeol = test['aeol'].values[0]
  diam = test['diameter'].values[0]
  delta_0 = 1/aeol * 0 + 0.15 + diam/120
# criterion for max P plus 10% (to extend the line a bit)
  max_load = max(load)
  delta_max = 1/aeol * max_load*1.1 + 0.15 + diam/120
  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  ax.plot(load, disp)
  ax.plot((0, max_load), (delta_0, delta_max), color= 'darkgray', linestyle = '--')
        # I added the coordinates manually, your program will have to get them
        # coordinated by curve fitting and solving the two equations
  ax.scatter(max_load, delta_max, edgecolors='r', facecolors='w', lw=3)
  ax.invert_yaxis()

  ax.set_xlabel('load')
  ax.set_ylabel('displacement')
  plt.legend(['load', 'criterion line', 'intersection point'], loc='lower left')
  plt.savefig(str(i)+"_slt.png")
```

Comment: can you print the content of the column like this `print(test['aeol'])` ? It seems the column is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will cause an error because the value retrieved is not a list and cannot be retrieved by specifying an index. So we convert it to a list and use the first value. (If this is not your logic, please change it.)

```
for i in df['lt_id'].unique():
    test = df.loc[df['lt_id'] == i]
    load = test['load']
    disp = test['displacement']
    aeol = test['aeol'].tolist()
    diam = test['diameter'].tolist()
    delta_0 = 1/aeol[0] * 0 + 0.15 + diam[0]/120
    # criterion for max P plus 10% (to extend the line a bit)
    max_load = max(load)
    delta_max = 1/aeol[0] * max_load*1.1 + 0.15 + diam[0]/120
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(load, disp)
    ax.plot((0, max_load), (delta_0, delta_max), color= 'darkgray', linestyle = '--')
        # I added the coordinates manually, your program will have to get them
        # coordinated by curve fitting and solving the two equations
    ax.scatter(max_load, delta_max, edgecolors='r', facecolors='w', lw=3)
    ax.invert_yaxis()

    ax.set_xlabel('load')
    ax.set_ylabel('displacement')
    plt.legend(['load', 'criterion line', 'intersection point'], loc='lower left')
#     plt.savefig(str(i)+"_slt.png")
```

[image]